# View contents below ExpandableListView

Tags: textview, scrollview, expandablelistview, android

I have a set of `TextView`s below an `ExpandableListView` in my `.xml` file. When the list expands all the `TextView`s get hidden below the screen. I tried putting my list in a `ScrollView` which turned out to be a very bad idea.

Is there any way for me to be able to scroll and view my `TextView`s?

This is my sample xml layout which could be of some use..

```
<RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/elv"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textview1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/elv"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="xyz" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/middle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvone"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/number" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number2" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number4" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/middle"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/my_account" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number5" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="number6" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/white_lable_bottom_"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_left_grey"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="15dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp"
                android:text="Log out" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did u try to fix the height of the expandable listview and add the entire textview under a new linear layout and add scroll to it.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, but it only makes the textview scrollable and when the expandablelistview expands the layout around the textview gets hidden below the screen. Now I want the entire thing (expandablelistview and textview) to be scrollable. Also, I dont want to fix the height of my expandablelistview.

Comment: Then another way would be to add the textviews to the expandable listview with child count as 0 for those so it wont expand but will look like a row

Comment: I have thought about that but did not put it in writing coz my expandablelistview has dynamic values and the bunch of textviews below it has a different layout. Is there any other possibility apart from this or do I have to try and stick with this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem and solved it with this layout.  The important part is setting the `layout_height` and `layout_weight` in the `ExpandableListView`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.gp.MyFragment">

    <ExpandableListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
            android:footerDividersEnabled="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Bailout"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]